# Interactive SVG: Change Fill Color onMouseOver

Tags: javascript, svg, onclick, onmouseover

I'm currently working on an imagemap in Addobe Illustrator CC and I want to be able to change the color of the shapes onMouseOver. Tried this in my SVG Interactivity panel:

```
style.fill="yellow"
```

and it doesn't seem to work. What would be the proper function to place there for onMouseOver?

My onClick event to link out to websites does work. That was:

```
location.href='https://thecleverroot.com/tag/southwest/';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change only styling, then you can use [CSS for SVG](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-and-css.html). Add class name to desired element and place the following code to your CSS file:

```
.className {
  color: yellow;
}

.className:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

if you want to redirect users to another URL onClick, there is no need to use JavaScript. You can add anchor element to your SVG and place href there. Here is a [nice article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/a-element.html) on this approach.

If you wish to style element while click use:

```
.className:active {
  color: red;
}
```

Use JavaScript only if your SVG should have some complex logic.

Comment: And that's the problem. It does have complex logic. It's a map of the US so it's a bunch of shapes grouped and then united together using Illustrator's pathfinder tool. The result is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Xmzowx

Comment: I should mention I tried this as well:
<a class="states1" xlink:href="https://yoursite.com/">
and then assigned a.states1:hover to a fill of #C00 or anything really, but while the link worked and the pointer cursor came up, which you'd expect for a link, the color did not change on hover.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution. Originally, Illustrator assigned fill styles to each shape in my group and not the group itself. Once I changed the fill references in my CSS to the ones in my group and not each individual path, I solved the problem and the hovers now work great without JS.